# Which version number for my JS framework?

Tags: javascript

What version number format would you follow for an Alpha release?

I've just finished writing a JS framework. It's working but needs some serious testing by other members of my team so I'd consider it to be in alpha. I need to give it a version number but I'm thinking that version 1.0.0 isn't correct as this is not a full release.

Comment: Usually a version.subversion<alpha/beta> is generally considered appropriate so a version could be something like this 0.1a.

Comment: I like this. Going to go with 0.1a

Comment: Nice good luck have fun! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no one right answer to this. I for one use the version number to keep track how close to "feature complete" a library is. Even though a library might be stable and ready to use, it doesn't mean it's ready in my mind.

It can help to come up with a roadmap and tie features to specific versions to guide the development effort. This is true particularly for larger projects that may include multiple developers.

You can use versions to signify API compatibility. If you are going to make really big changes that break the backwards compatibility, doing a x.0 release might be in order.

It is useful to utilize a build tool such as [grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt). It will help a lot in packaging and overall makes your life easier.

Comment: Yes, this is how I want to think about it. The version number should symbolic of the state the library is in.